# Mysqli prepared statement unwanted results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

Can someone please tell me why this doesn work all the times ?

```
include('../globals/mysqli_connect.php'); 
              $insert_channel = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
              if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
                }

                $insert_channel_query = "UPDATE tv_channels SET channel_name='$_POST[channel_name]', variant_1_source='$_POST[variant_1_source]', variant_2_source='$_POST[variant_2_source]' , variant_3_source='$_POST[variant_3_source]', variant_4_source='$_POST[variant_4_source]'  WHERE id =?";
                if ($stmt_insert_channel = $insert_channel->prepare($insert_channel_query)) {
                    $stmt_insert_channel->bind_param("s",$_GET['editchannelID']);
                    $stmt_insert_channel->execute();
                    $stmt_insert_channel->close(); 

                    }

                     $insert_channel->close();
                     header("refresh:1;url=tv_online.php");
```

The thing is it works but when in $_Post['variant_1_source'] or $_Post['variant_2_source'] or
$_Post['variant_3_source'] or $_Post['variant_4_source'] i add this :

```
<script src="http://portaltv.ro/jw6/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://portaltv.ro/jw6/key.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/3/jwpsrv.js"></script><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/3/sharing.js"></script></head><body><div id="player_1_wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;"><object name="player_1" width="100%" height="100%" tabindex="0" id="player_1" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" "=""><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="50800"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="13123"><PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="http://portaltv.ro/jw6/jwplayer.flash.swf"><PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="http://portaltv.ro/jw6/jwplayer.flash.swf"><PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Opaque"><PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High"><PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE="LT"><PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="always"><PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="NoScale"><PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE="000000"><PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all"><PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="true"><PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreenInteractive" VALUE="false"><PARAM NAME="IsDependent" VALUE="0"><param name="movie" value="http://portaltv.ro/jw6/jwplayer.flash.swf"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"></object><div id="player_1_jwpsrv" style="top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 10;"></div><div id="player_1_sharing" style="top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 11;"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('player_1').setup({
            file: "http://178.21.120.198:1936/live3/mp4:animalplanet/mp4:animalplanet/portaltv.m3u8?file=mp4:animalplanet&token=f526074b3aa399ec6b82df17ce1d5840",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            autostart: "true",
            sharing: {
            code: encodeURI("<iframe src='http://www.x'/>"),
            link: "http://www.x"
                       }
        });
    </script>
```

it doesn't insert the above code into the database .
P.S. i know its not safe to put variables directly into the query ,i did it just for testing.If someone can tell me why isn't the html/javascript added to the database ,please help a brother out . Thank you !

Comment: The value of the `$_POST` variable is all that HTML? The problem is that it contains quotes, and you're not escaping them. If you use placeholders for them, you wouldn't have this problem. You seem to know how to use placeholders, since you use it for the ID field.

Comment: Jesus , sometimes i wonder "why can't i see the problem when its right there ,in my face" ,that was it , thank you very much ,you helped me alot .